# Is there any cassandra C++ client library which is thread safe?

Tags: c++, cassandra

I am looking for a client library which is thread safe . If you can provide me with an example for multithread insertion it will help me a lot !

Many thanks.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you are still interested... anyway, the standard c++ client library at the moment is [cpp-driver](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver).

It is quite straightforward to use, even though still missing many functionalities of its java-python counterpart.

Doing multi-thread insertions is as easy as sharing the "session" instance amongst threads. You will know what I mean if you just look at the simple demo app provided with the driver.